# Why can't I change the value of a Json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to update the value *"customer.signature"* but my code does not do, what I want him to do. JSON and HTML are without errors, that influence what I want. 
The problem is, my JS is not working.   **"data.signature"** is updating fine. but **"data.customer.signature"**  is not.

Json (which I get by rest "Accounts"):

```
{
  "signature": "newAccountSignatur",
  "signatureEnabled": true,
  "defaultMsisdn": "08282709909013",
  "httpForwardingAddress": "http://null.dev.to",
  "smtpForwardingAddress": "lazarus@null.dev.to",
  "customer": {
    "signature": "newCustomerSignatur",
    "id": 10339,
    "companyName": "Gerd Webapp Test v2.0.x",
    "diallingCodeId": 43,
  },
}
```

Js:

```
$scope.saveSignature = function () {
  if (AuthService.isAuth()) {
    Accounts.one().get().then(
        function (resultOk) {
          resultOk.data.customer.signature = $scope.newCustomerSig;
          resultOk.data.signature = $scope.newAccountSig;
          $log.d("resultOk: ", resultOk.data);
          resultOk.data.put().then(
              function (resultOk) {
                alert("Saved");
                $log.d("Accountinfo ok: ", resultOk);
                $scope.user = resultOk.data;
              },
              function (resultError) {
                $log.d("Accountinfo error: ", resultError);
                ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
              }
          );
        }
    );
  }
};
```

html:

```
<form name="signature" ng-sub>
    <div>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newAccountSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.signature}}"></textarea>
    </div>
    <i> Persönliche Signatur </i><br/>
    <div>
      <i> Zweites Beispiel</i><br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newCustomerSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.customer.signature}}"></textarea>
    </div>
    <i>Information für mich: </i>
    <p>Aktueller Wert in account.signature = </p>
    <span>{{user.signature| stringIfBlank:'-'}}</span>
    <p>Aktueller Wert in account.customer.signature = </p>
    <span>{{user.customer.signature| stringIfBlank:'-'}}</span>
  </form>
```

Comment: can u post the full json data ... and also check browser console for any errors

Comment: ok, I fixed it, the problem was the order of the nesting.. 

Browserconsole ( netbeans + chrome ) didnt reply anything..that was a probem.. thanks anyway

Comment: @Flowdo you have the option to answer your own question, in the benefit of others

Comment: oh kay, thanks!  didnt know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE*** the order of the nesting was the problem. for those who maybe have to handle familiar problems.. I wont remove this.

```
   $scope.saveSignature = function () {
      if (AuthService.isAuth()) {
        AccountCustomer.one().get().then(
            function (resultOk) {
              resultOk.data.signature = $scope.newCustomerSig;
              resultOk.data.put().then(
                  Accounts.one().get().then(
                  function (resultOk) {
                    resultOk.data.signature = $scope.newAccountSig;
                    resultOk.data.put().then(
                        function (resultOk) {
                          alert("Saved");
                          $log.d("Accountinfo ok: ", resultOk);
                          $scope.user = resultOk.data;
                        },
                        function (resultError) {
                          $log.d("Accountinfo error: ", resultError);
                          ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
                        }
                    );
                  }
              ));
            }
        );
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example : [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/luhoquyufinu/1/)

```
var data ={
  "signature": "newAccountSignatur",
  "signatureEnabled": true,
  "defaultMsisdn": "08282709909013",
  "httpForwardingAddress": "http://null.dev.to",
  "smtpForwardingAddress": "lazarus@null.dev.to",
  "customer": {
    "signature": "newCustomerSignatur",
    "id": 10339,
    "companyName": "Gerd Webapp Test v2.0.x",
    "diallingCodeId": 43,
  },
};
data.customer.signature="newsign";
console.log(data.customer.signature);
alert(data.customer.signature);
```